# php include statement is not including my php file to the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

when i trying to include `tabnav_Browse.php` page which is located on `includes` directory and `Browse_Page1.php` is another file which is located on `Browse` directory by putting this code on the page `<?php include    ("../includes/tabnav_Browse.php"); ?>`but it shows nothing on the `Browse_Page1.php` page not even any kind of errors. actually this problem is persist since i starting this jquery ajax function to load my pages dynamically without page reload. but i am successfully included the `footer.php` and `stylesheets_fonts_js.php` to the `index.php` both these two files are also in the `includes` folder just like `tabnav_Browse.php`! then why `tabnav_Browse.php` is not going to include and other two does?
i tried different variations like `<?php include    ("../includes/tabnav_Browse.php"); ?>` `<?php include   ("/includes/tabnav_Browse.php"); ?>` `<?php include ("./includes/tabnav_Browse.php"); ?>` but nothing works!
here is my files structure

- Browse
- Includes
- index.php

this is my nav menu.

```
 <nav>
 <ul id='menu' class="menu-items">
 <li><a href="#Browse_Page1" class="albums active" id="page1-link"><i class="arcd-archive"></i></br>Browse</a></li>
 <li><a href="#Top_albums_Page1" class="pages" id="page2-link"><i class="arcd-music97"></i></br>Top albums</a></li>
 <li><a href="#Top_artists_Page1" class="albums" id="page3-link"><i class="arcd-microphone52"></i></br>Top artists</a></li>
 <li><a href="#Top_lists_Page1" class="pages" id="page4-link"><i class="arcd-numbered8"></i></br>Top lists</a></li>
 <li><a href="#Charts_Page1" class="pages" id="page4-link"><i class="arcd-rising9"></i></br>Charts</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
```

and this is the jquery ajax function i am talking about along with load.php file.

```
  $(function () {
  $('header nav a').on('click', function () {
    var linkClicked = $(this).attr('href');
    var data = {
        page      : linkClicked.replace(/\D/g, ''),
        directory : linkClicked.replace(/(_Page(.*)|#)/g,'')
    }

    $("header nav a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('#loading').css('visibility', 'visible');

    $.post('load.php', data, function(msg) {
        $('#main-content').html(msg);
        $('#loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $('#main-content section').hide().fadeIn();
      }, 'html');
    });
  });
```

load.php

```
  <?php
    $page = filter_var( $_POST['page'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $dir  = filter_var( $_POST['directory'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if ( $page !== false && $dir !== false ) {
    $link = $dir . '/' . $dir . '_Page' . $page . '.html';
    if ( file_exists( $link ) ) {
    echo file_get_contents( $link );
    } else {
        echo 'There is no such page!';
     }
    }
  ?>
```

please help me! any help will be very appreciated! thanks

Comment: Add ini_set('display_errors', 1); as the first line of your PHP file, it will allow the errors to display.  The problem is probably a path issue.

Comment: @ user2182349 thanks for support can you understand my question `load.php` works fine the reason why i posted this file because it is using by jquery ajax function which i loaded pages in the navigation menu. as for as path concerns i am 100% sure that is correct and as you also see folders structure above! what is going on i don't know!

Comment: Use the browser console or network tab to see what file is being requested by jQuery

Comment: as i said jquery function perfectly loads pages but when i load a page that include another page then that page is loaded successfully but it doesn't contain included page! e.g `tabnav_Browse.php` is included in the `Browse_Page1.php` by php include function but when `Browse_Page1.php` loads through above jquery ajax function i doesn't showed `tabnav_Browse.php` there in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Should there be two $dirs in this line?

```
$link = $dir . '/' . $dir . '_Page' . $page . '.html';
```

or should it look like this?

```
$link = $dir . '_Page' . $page . '.html';
```

For that matter, you could simplify your code and not use Ajax, or change the href to "#" and use a data-file attribute, like so:

```
 <li><a href="#" data-file="Top_artists1" class="albums" id="page3-link"><i class="arcd-microphone52"></i></br>Top artists</a></li>
```

With this for JavaScript

```
$(function () {
$('header nav a').on('click', function () {
    var data = {
        html: $(this).attr('data-file');
    }

    $("header nav a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('#loading').css('visibility', 'visible');

    $.post('load.php', data, function(msg) {
         $('#main-content').html(msg);
         $('#loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');
         $('#main-content section').hide().fadeIn();
     }, 'html');
  });
});
```

And on the server (**load.php**):

```
<?php
    $url  = preg_match( '/\w+/', $_POST['data-file']);
    if ( $url !== 0 ) {
        if ( file_exists( $file ) ) {
            echo file_get_contents( $file );
        } else {
            echo 'There is no such page!';
    }
  }
```